# ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "+xxxxxxxxxxx"

Tags: python, telethon

I want to get the telegram Id of the user from their phone number. The user phone number is saved in my contact list and we never interact with each other. But my contact number is not known to the user.
can I fetch the id of the user?

```
    for mobile in newuser['Mobile']:
        mob = '+91' + str(mobile)
        user = await clients.get_entity(mob)
        print(user)
```

Comment: You have to save the contact

Comment: uncleaned code https://gist.github.com/SmartManoj/aceee7302d5fcbe0721814d26e3f7d01

Comment: user also need to save my contact number? previously i tried and it worked.

Comment: No, they don't need to save